# OpenLayers installation using npm - packet not found

Tags: npm, debian, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am trying to install *openlayers* within my Express project using npm to create custom builds but I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'mapbox/vector-tile' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'openlayers'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "openlayers"
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR!
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried updating *npm* and installing *vector-tile* manually but it didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: same error when calling `npm install ol` instead of `npm install openlayers`.

Comment: openlayers depends on mapbox vector-tiles. You can try to install it using "npm install @mapbox/vector-tile". I think there might have been some error downloading the vector-tile package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a more recent version of node and npm, preferably the LTS versions

Comment: Thank you! Upgrading to npm 5.3.0 solved my problem.